# How to order two tables with no relationship and different columns, by a single column that they share (date)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've got two tables in a MYSQL database. One Is a for blog posts and one is for videos. All the columns in each of them are different except for one which is the date they were created.

On the main page of my website I want to show most recent posts, whether that be a video or a blog post. So I want to order them based on their shared date column. Is this something I can do in MYSQL or would I have to pull all the data into php and then order it using my own function.

I've looked up other answers but they all seem to be cases where the tables have no relationship but share the same columns.

Comment: You could try a union

Comment: you can add you structure data mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For table to be used in the same result set as you are suggesting, you would need a UNION; but UNIONs require all union-ed queries to have the same columns in their results. If the only field in common you have is "date"; the best you could probably do is something like.

```
SELECT `date` AS postDate, 'Video' AS postType
, someVideoField, null as someBlogField
FROM video_table
UNION 
SELECT `date` AS postDate, 'Blog' AS postType
, null as someVideoField, someBlogField
FROM blog_table
ORDER BY postDate
;
```

*Note: The latter aliases are not actually needed, I just tend to do that for clarity as to which field is expected to map to which. Also, the `null as someBlogField` portion may need tweaked to insure the result field is a type that can accept the real values from the latter half of the union; the first half determines field types.*

Comment: Don't you need a second SELECT, or is that okay to omit with UNION? Also, will the ORDER BY refer to the entire query or just the second select? I was thinking about this but I couldn't remember how it worked exactly.

Comment: This works perfectly thanks!

Comment: I added in a second select and it works fine

Comment: yeah, sorry, typo...corrected for posterity; ORDER BY refers to entire UNION

Answer (score 0):

If you end up using two queries it's easy enough to put them together in your script.

```
while ($row = $blogQuery->fetch()) {
    $results[$row['date']]['blog'] = $row;
}

while ($row = $videoQuery->fetch()) {
    $results[$row['date']]['video'] = $row;
}
```

If you ordered by date in your select queries, this will already be *mostly* in the right order, except for dates where only the video query has rows (or whichever one you fetched second). You can `ksort($results)` to fix the order for any of those.